# htaccess redirect from index.php to / only in specific folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want create redirect in my htaccess file. From url with index.php to page without index.php, but only for one specific folder "catalog".

For example:

from `/catalog/some_folder/index.php` to `/catalog/some_folder/` or

from `/catalog/some_folder/etc/index.php` to `/catalog/some_folder/etc/`

URL like this `/catalog2/some_folder/index.php` don't must redirect

I try add those lines(localhost because it was xampp):

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /catalog/+[^\.]+index.php$
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ localhost/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this didn't work. How can i force this to work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(catalog/.+)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: something must be wrong in my configuration it is sending me up one level (i am in localhost/myproject/index.php) and (it is sending me to localhost/)

Comment: To make it work in `/myproject` just change target URI in last rule as `/myproject/$1`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you need to remove all "index.php" at the end of the address

Answer (score 0):

To remove index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Remember,you will need to activate mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (?:/[^/]*)*/index\.php[?#\ ]
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}/../ [L,R=301]
```

For me this is working the solution above is sending me to a folder up one level.